# extracting a file without letting the user access it

Tags: c#

I was always pretty impressed by those programs that you could install by executing one installer file, which would then extract all the other required files to run the actual program.
And even now im still wondering how you would code a program that extracts files that are literally still inside the program ( so not in some kind of zip) , i've seen tons of installers for games who have this.  I need this cause I want to extract a file on the right moment without giving the person who uses the program the ability to delete the file before its extracted, this may seem vague, but I hope i've informed you enough.

Comment: are you referring to deployment tools such as InstallShield

Comment: In general if a user does not have read access to a file then an application ran by that user will not have read access to the file.  Your question is not clear.  How an installer works is well documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about changing the build action for the file you want to hide to Embedded Resource, or something like that that compiles the file inside the dll/exe?

Comment: @JameyDiepbrink thanks, go ahead and accept the answer so future visitors to this page know what worked for you (and I get points :))

Answer (score 3):

I'm just going to say that building an installer is *difficult*.

I'd recommend using NSIS: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page

As for creating a file the user can't access, create a temp file with the correct read/write permissions, extract the data to the temp file, then copy the file where it needs to go.

Extract happens without the user interfering, and copy protection is handled by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Executable program  is just file, So you can append any data at you executables. (works for my c++ compiled program)

```
$ cat executables some_blob_data > new_executables
```

Since argv[0] of main() is name of your file, you can use this to acess data in this file itself (works for c or c++ and likley for other languages to)

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way to do this is to use your archive tool or one of the dozens of already made installers. WinRar, WinZip and most others allow the creation of self extracting exe files. I know you've said that is not what you want but if you make sure to make it auto exec your installer app and remove all of the temporary files when you're done it really can be very fool proof and professional looking. Obviously, the various installer applications are able to do what you're wanting.

If you really want to do this yourself the easy solution is going to most likely be dependant on your IDE software and language. The generic answer is that you'll need a compression library which can accept a stream as input. Then you'll want to make your actual files into resources inside your installer app. At that point it's just a matter of telling the compression library to read from a stream which is pointed at the resource. How that is done varies greatly from language to language.